# PHP multidimensional array to html

Tags: php, arrays

I am new to PHP and have run into some problems regarding arrays. I have my SQL query set up which is

```
    SELECT SUM(expenseAmount.expenseAmount) as expenseAmount, expenseSubcatagory.Subcatagory_name,  expenseCatagory.catagoryName
    FROM expenseAmount
    INNER JOIN expenseSubcatagory ON expenseAmount.Subcatagory_id = expenseSubcatagory.Subcatagory_id
    INNER JOIN expenseCatagory ON expenseSubcatagory.catagory_id = expenseCatagory.catagory_id
    WHERE expenseAmount.dateEntered
    BETWEEN '2018-08-01' AND '2018-09-29'
    GROUP BY expenseCatagory.catagoryName, expenseSubcatagory.Subcatagory_name;
    This equals 
    ___________
    expenseAmount | Subcatagory_name | catagoryName
    495           |  credit card     | debt Reduction
    495           |  Special Occasion| gifts
    98            |  Gym Memberships | personal
    80            |  Emergency Fund  | saving
    46            |  Birthday        | gifts
    40            |  Student Loan    |  debt Reduction
```

I want to insert this data into my html in an output similar to

```
<div id="content1" >
    <h2 class="writing">debt Reduction</h2>
    <div class= "col-xs-6 expenseDivide">
        <label class="label-expose">credit card</label>
        <input type="text" value="495 ">
        <label class="label-expose">Student Loan</label>
        <input type="text" value="40 ">
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to create a loop to follow this fashion, so all the catagoryNames are grouped together.

I created this array which sort of assisted me

```
   $groupedCatagories = array();
   foreach ($resultsOfQuery as $row)
   {
      $groupedCatagories[$row['catagoryName']][$row['Subcatagory_name']][] = 
     $row['expenseAmount'];
    }
```

but this results in

```
/home/vagrant/code/phpTests/testtttt.php:128:
            array (size=4)
           'debt Reduction' => 
        array (size=2)
          'credit card ' => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => string '495.00' (length=6)
          'Student Loan' => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => string '40.00' (length=5)
      'gifts' => 
        array (size=2)
          'Birthday' => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => string '46.00' (length=5)
          'Special Occasion' => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => string '495.00' (length=6)
      'personal' => 
        array (size=1)
          'Gym Memberships' => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => string '98.00' (length=5)
      'saving' => 
        array (size=1)
          'Emergency Fund' => 
            array (size=1)
              0 => string '80.00' (length=5)
/home/vagrant/code/phpTests/testtttt.php:128:
        array (size=4)
          'debt Reduction' => 
            array (size=2)
              'credit card ' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => string '495.00' (length=6)
              'Student Loan' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => string '40.00' (length=5)
          'gifts' => 
            array (size=2)
              'Birthday' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => string '46.00' (length=5)
              'Special Occasion' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => string '495.00' (length=6)
          'personal' => 
            array (size=1)
              'Gym Memberships' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => string '98.00' (length=5)
          'saving' => 
            array (size=1)
              'Emergency Fund' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => string '80.00' (length=5)
/home/vagrant/code/phpTests/testtttt.php:128:
            array (size=4)
              'debt Reduction' => 
                array (size=2)
                  'credit card ' => 
                    array (size=1)
                      0 => string '495.00' (length=6)
                  'Student Loan' => 
                    array (size=1)
                      0 => string '40.00' (length=5)
              'gifts' => 
                array (size=2)
                  'Birthday' => 
                    array (size=1)
                      0 => string '46.00' (length=5)
                  'Special Occasion' => 
                    array (size=1)
                      0 => string '495.00' (length=6)
              'personal' => 
                array (size=1)
                  'Gym Memberships' => 
                    array (size=1)
                      0 => string '98.00' (length=5)
              'saving' => 
                array (size=1)
                  'Emergency Fund' => 
                    array (size=1)
                      0 => string '80.00' (length=5)
/home/vagrant/code/phpTests/testtttt.php:128:


    array (size=4)
              'debt Reduction' => 
                array (size=2)
                  'credit card ' => 
                    array (size=1)
                      0 => string '495.00' (length=6)
                  'Student Loan' => 
                    array (size=1)
                      0 => string '40.00' (length=5)
              'gifts' => 
                array (size=2)
                  'Birthday' => 
                    array (size=1)
                      0 => string '46.00' (length=5)
                  'Special Occasion' => 
                    array (size=1)
                      0 => string '495.00' (length=6)
              'personal' => 
                array (size=1)
                  'Gym Memberships' => 
                    array (size=1)
                      0 => string '98.00' (length=5)
              'saving' => 
                array (size=1)
                  'Emergency Fund' => 
                    array (size=1)
                      0 => string '80.00' (length=5)
```

As you can see, does not really solve the problem, if anyone could assist It would be amazing.

Apologies for my ignorance.

Jack.

Comment: Just make sure `id="content1"` didn't get repeated. It's a violation of HTML standards

Comment: Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reduce the extra depth in your array definition as it's not needed.

```
$groupedCatagories[$row['catagoryName']][$row['Subcatagory_name']] = $row['expenseAmount'];
```

Then loop through your groups to uncover the individual categories and subcategories. Since we removed the extra array depth, we can simply output the value.

```
 <div id="content1" >
    <?php foreach ($groupedCatagories as $category => $subCategories) : ?>
      <h2 class="writing"><?= $category ?></h2>
      <div class= "col-xs-6 expenseDivide">
         <?php foreach ($subCategories as $title => $amount) : ?>
            <label class="label-expose"><?= $title ?></label>
            <input type="text" value="<?= $amount ?>">
         <?php endforeach; ?>
     </div>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this sorted it perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 loops and you can nest those in the template.

```
<?php
foreach($groupedCatagories as $groupName => $subCategories) {
?>
<div id="content1">
    <h2 class="writing"><?=$groupName?></h2>
    <div class= "col-xs-6 expenseDivide">
        <?php
        foreach($subCategories as $subName => $values) {
        ?>
        <label class="label-expose"><?=$subName?></label>
        <input type="text" value="<?=array_sum($values)?>">
        <?php
        } // end subCategories
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
} // end groupedCategories
?>
```

If you don't need arrays of values then you should sum them in SQL or in your PHP code.